# Spaceship image is failing to move. Is there an error in my code?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, keyboard, atom-editor

I am using a book called Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes. A part of the book deals with python code projects and I started coding for an Alien Invasion Game. I attached the code written so far for the game to work but whenever I run the code, the spaceship does not move regardless of whether I press my keyboard's right or left key. I have ran the code several times but my editor doesn't indicate that there are errors. Is there something I need to fix in my code? I would greatly appreciate it if someone knows how to fix this.
Alien_invasion.py code:

```
import sys

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

        # Set the background color.
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self.ship.update()
            self._update_screen()
            # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = True

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    self.ship.moving_right = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    self.ship.moving_left = False

                    # Move the ship to the right.
                    self.ship.rect.x += 1

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Ship.py code:

```
import pygame

class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Movement flags
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """Update the ship's position based on the movement flag."""
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.x += 1
        if self.moving_left:
            self.rect.x -= 1

        # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Settings.py code:

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's settings."""
        # Screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_height = 800
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please don't post your code as screenshots. This makes it impossible to copy/paste it in order to test. Use a code block to format your code in the post.

Comment: Pasting your code in the post would be helpful to everyone. Have you considered running your program from a shell instead through atom?

Comment: @pavel Thank you so much for replying to my post! I have learned to add code blocks and inserted my code that way. Was this able to help you spot the error?

Comment: @abhivemp Thank you for replying to my post! I have learned to paste in my code. I am not familiar with running code by shell. Was the pasted code able to help you spot an error?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code, all seems to be fine. One thing is that there's an unnecessary code in `_check_events()` method.  There's no need to have `self.ship.rect.x += 1` there because `Ship` class is meant to deal with adjusting ship's `rect` parameters. But I doubt it's the reason for the issues you're having.

Comment: @SukiLee `python fileName.py` or whatever your executive file is named as in your configurations. That will let you run the code and see the output in the shell. If you get any errors, paste it here in the post

Answer (score 0):

I got the code working, it was a typo error.

```
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if **event.key** == pygame.K_RIGHT: 
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif **event.key** == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True

    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if **event.key** == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif **event.key** == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False
```

Earlier I coded event.type instead of event.key

The code is working now, will continue working on the project.